# Detecting a sort in officeJS Excel

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I just started working on an office add-in and I was wondering if there's any way to detect a sort initiated by the user?

I would be happy with even a potential sort, as long as it is different from a user making an edit. I checked the [eventType enum](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/eventtype-enumeration) 
and it seems like what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exposed event for it.  Actually, I don't believe there is an event for it even in VBA/VSTO.

What is the scenario you are trying to accomplish?  What would happen if someone without your add-in were to sort manually, would your data end up in a broken state?  If so, then you might want to think your design to somehow capture the data integrity in a way that doesn't rely on listening to a sort event.

Comment: I'm bringing data into a spreadsheet from a database. If the user does a partial sort and then saves back to the database, my data is useless.

Comment: True.  But what if they do a partial sort while your add-in is closed?  Or when they (or another user) are on another computer, without the add-in installed?  I think that your best bet is to add a "key" column and/or add other validation logic to ensure that the data is in a consistent state.  Just having an event would add a layer of safety, but not much of one.